What should our logo and site design look like?
I know that it's a bit early to ask, but it takes tome to come out with a good idea, so accumulating bright proposals should be useful.

It's a bit early, also mostly useless. The design will come in months if not over a year's time, and is done by a professional. The “seven essential meta questions” post is unfortunately somewhat out of date.

Gilles, can you post it as answer, we could close the question then...

@Gilles How so? Communities are supposed to discuss and contribute to their design ideas.

@RobertCartaino Are they? It doesn't seem to ever have an impact.

At the moment, there are other issues that need to be discussed first like the site scope

In the distant future when this is considered, I propose a design around 0x90: the hex memory location usually associated with a successful exploit, which Reverse Engineering is searching for. Also ties nicely into whole Stack Overflow theme.

@lizz:  0x90 is actually the numeric value of a nop, used in nop sleds which lead to shell code. the value isn't a memory location, though.
